# How to rewrite HttpRequestMessage call to support <T>

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net

I found a useful class that makes Web API calls with JSON serialize/deserialize support of type T. You can view the entire class/article [here](http://johnnycode.com/2012/02/23/consuming-your-own-asp-net-web-api-rest-service/). I think I could get a lot of use out of this class and would like to try it. There is one error left that I can't figure out how to handle. It's in the following routine:

```
protected HttpRequestMessage GetHttpRequestMessage<T>(T data)
{
    MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    JsonSerializerSettings jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    jsonSerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter());

    JsonNetFormatter jsonFormatter = new JsonNetFormatter(jsonSerializerSettings);

    HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage<T>(data, mediaType, new MediaTypeFormatter[] { jsonFormatter });

    return requestMessage;
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Error   3   The non-generic type 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage' 
cannot be used with type arguments.
```

Where `HttpRequestMessage<T>` is underlined with a red squiggly.

How would I rewrite this routine/line of code in a way that will not break the generic usefulness of this class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That article is out of date; it is referencing the BETA version of Web API.  The generic `HttpRequestMessage<T>` class was removed in the released version [as explained here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/350492).  Instead you should use the [`PostAsJsonAsync<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944521%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) extension method.  Here is a more [up-to-date tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) that should give you what you need.

Comment: The tutorial made sense of things. Thank you Brian.